# Why is not GHC optimizing for constants?

Tags: haskell, optimization, ghc

```
import Data.List
a = foldl' (+) 0 [1..99999999]
main = putStrLn $ show $ a
```

This program takes a while to run. But `a` does not depend on anything and thus is constant. It could be perfectly calculated at compile time. Why is not GHC optimizing for this? Is there a flag for it to do so, or should I just replace that kind of constant calculation by the values themselves?

Comment: `a` isn't actually quite constant because it's polymorphic. GHC deduces the type as `(Num a, Enum a) => a`, which internally translates to a function requiring class dictionary arguments.
(However even if you make it `a :: Int`, the value will be calculated only at runtime.)

Comment: What you are talking about is called supercompilation and it's not quite as easy as you make it seem. It's a research subject and I believe some people are testing this with Haskell, but it's nowhere near production ready. You can get it with some Template Haskell hackery, but it's not generally recommended.

Answer (score 13):

This is not a perfect solution, but as kqr already remarked you can of course achieve your goal with Template Haskell:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Language.Haskell.TH
import Data.List

a :: Integer
a = $( return . LitE . IntegerL $ foldl' (+) 0 [1..99999999] )

main = print a
```

This generates the integer literal `4999999950000000` from the fold expression, before actually starting to compile the program.

Answer (score 7):

This is the same as the discussion covered by [this reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/1kpu1h/can_haskell_programs_be_compiled_such_that_the/) thread. Basically, what you want is but a simple case which is uncommon in practice. Optimizing with constant folding quickly turns into problems regarding Gödel's theorem and the Halting problem.

Comment: Why can't there just be a pragma that says "compute this at compile time" so that the responsibility of proving termination is on the programmer?

Comment: Because noone can enforce that flag not to be used every time. And what happens if someone has a code which can be turned into a constant only if Goldbach's is true?

Comment: I don't understand how that applies.  All I'm asking is a compiler pragma that tells `ghc` to try to compute the value at compile time.  If it doesn't terminate, then I'm okay with that.

Comment: Well.. how do you it doesn't terminate or you just have to wait one more minute of compilation time? Or, maybe one more day?

Comment: That's fine with me.  I don't mind if I don't know if it will terminate.  Like I said, the burden of worrying about termination on the programmer, and I'm happy to wait until I'm tired of waiting.

Comment: But when will you know that you're right to be tired or not? If you interrupt the compilation you won't get a partial result and you cannot get back the spent CPU cycles

Comment: I don't know if I'm right, but that's okay.  Like I said, just let me worry about that.  After all, Haskell already has `UndecidableInstances` which moves the burden of proof of decidability to the programmer, so why is this any different?  Just let the programmer worry about whether or not it is decidable.

Comment: Things are simpler with `UndecidableInstances`. The proof regarding their failure is decidable

Comment: But they knew that they'll have a bridge in the end. You don't know that you'll get an executable after the compilation.

Comment: @MihaiMaruseac Human-provided annotations are a relatively common strategy for giving the compiler facts about individual special cases that are impossible to deduce automatically in general. `unsafePerformIO` and friends are in fact exactly this; by using them you assert that it is okay to perform *this* particular `IO` action as if it was a pure function, and the resulting disaster if you were wrong is your problem. Mercury's versions of the same things are explicitly called "promises", and it even has one about termination analysis.

Comment: You can achieve supercompilation of simple expressions relatively easy using TH. A brief introduction to this can be found here: https://github.com/quchen/articles/blob/master/useful_techniques.md#poor-mans-supercompiler

Comment: Another idea that would avoid annotations and still be deterministic: execute n steps and see if it terminates.

Comment: What if it terminates in step (n+1)?

Comment: @MihaiMaruseac: Ben and David are right. TH is literally designed for this.